# How to treat numbers in list as integers in function

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that finds both the signed/unsigned max/min values given a bit length. But every time I execute the function I get an error, here is my code

```
#function to find max and min number of both signed and unsigned bit values

    def minmax (n) :
        for numbers in n :

            unsignedmax = (2**n)-1
            unsignedmin = 0
            signedmax = 2**(n-1)-1
            signedmin = -2**(n-1)
        print "number     ", "unsigned              ", "signed"

    #Main

    bitlist = [2, 3, 8, 10, 16, 20, 32]

    minmax(bitlist)
```

the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Issac94/Documents/Python Files/sanchez-hw07b.py", line 23, in <module>
    minmax(bitlist)
  File "C:/Users/Issac94/Documents/Python Files/sanchez-hw07b.py", line 6, in minmax
    unsignedmax = (2**n)-1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'list'
>>>
```

I wasn't done writing it but ran it to make sure there was no error in the logic part but i get that one error when trying to find the values. Is there maybe a way to insert int() or something similar to have the number be treated as type integer and not tyle list which im assuming is happening?

Comment: `n` (by parameter `bitlist`) is a list and you are trying to raise 2 to the power of a list ! Seems you have swapped `n` and `numbers` somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Change the method definition and first line to this:

```
def minmax (numbers) :
    for n in numbers :
```

That is, in these two lines, replace 'n' with 'numbers' everywhere it appears and replace 'numbers' with 'n' where it appers.

As you have it written the variable "numbers" holds the item in the list you want to process and the variable "n" is holding the list.  But the rest of your code is written with the reverse assumption.